# python3: select() behaves weird with UNIX FIFO

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, unix, select

I am trying to wait on a UNIX FIFO for some input string. I am using select() to wait on FD to be ready to be read. For te first time my code waits as expected, but then select() keeps returning with success even if FD is no more ready to be read.

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import errno
import time
import sys
import os
import select
import string

myInput = './inFIFO'
try:
    if os.path.exists(myInput):
        os.unlink(myInput)
    os.mkfifo(myInput)
except Exception as e:
    sys.stderr.write("ERROR: " + str(e))
    sys.exit(2)

sIn = open(myInput, 'r')

try:
    loop = 5
    while loop:
        loop = loop - 1
        readMe = select.select([sIn], [], [])[0]
        print(readMe, file = sys.stderr);
        if len(readMe):
            a = sIn.readlines()
            print('Message <|' + ''.join(a) + '|>', file = sys.stderr)
            sIn.flush()
except Exception as e:
    sys.stderr.write('ERROR: ' + str(e))
    sys.stdin.close()
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stderr.close()
    os.unlink(myStdin)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Here is the Output:

```
root:~# ./select.py &
[1] 4035
root:~# echo 'Hello World !!!' > ./inFIFO
root:~# [<_io.TextIOWrapper name='./inFIFO' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <|Hello World !!!
|>
[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='./inFIFO' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <||>
[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='./inFIFO' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <||>
[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='./inFIFO' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <||>
[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='./inFIFO' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <||>

[1]+  Done                    ./select.py
root:~#
```

Why is select() behaving unusual?
I am using LinuxMint 19 amd64 and Python 3.6.6

**UPDATE:**

Updated the code with `os.read()` still the same story...

New code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import errno
import time
import sys
import os
import select
import string

myInput = './inFIFO'
try:
    if os.path.exists(myInput):
        os.unlink(myInput)
    os.mkfifo(myInput)
except Exception as e:
    sys.stderr.write("ERROR: " + str(e))
    sys.exit(2)

sIn = open(myInput, 'r')

try:
    loop = 5
    while loop:
        loop = loop - 1
        readMe = select.select([sIn], [], [])[0]
        print(readMe, file = sys.stderr);
        if len(readMe):
            a = os.read(sIn.fileno(), 8192).decode()
            print('Message <|' + ''.join(a) + '|>', file = sys.stderr)
            sIn.flush()
except Exception as e:
    sys.stderr.write('ERROR: ' + str(e))
    sys.stdin.close()
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stderr.close()
    os.unlink(myStdin)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Now output is:

```
root:~# ./select.py &
[1] 4099
root:~# echo 'Hello World !!!' > ./inFIFO
root:~# [<_io.TextIOWrapper name='./inFIFO' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <|Hello World !!!
|>
[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='./inFIFO' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <||>
[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='./inFIFO' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <||>
[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='./inFIFO' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <||>
[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='./inFIFO' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <||>

[1]+  Done                    ./select.py
root:~#
```

Comment: Don't use buffered I/O (`.readlines`) with `select.select`, they may interact weirdly. Use `os.read` instead. Please extend the question with the console output after replacing `sIn.readlines()` with `os.read(sIn.fileno(), 8192)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by opening the FIFO as READ-WRITE and NON-BLOCK I/O.

My working code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import errno
import time
import sys
import os
import select
import string

myInput = './inFIFO'
try:
    if os.path.exists(myInput):
        os.unlink(myInput)
    os.mkfifo(myInput)
except Exception as e:
    sys.stderr.write("ERROR: " + str(e))
    sys.exit(2)

inFD = os.open(myInput, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK)
sIn = os.fdopen(inFD, 'r')

try:
    loop = 5
    while loop:
        loop = loop - 1
        readMe = select.select([sIn], [], [])[0]
        print(readMe, file = sys.stderr);
        if len(readMe):
            a = sIn.read()
            print('Message <|' + ''.join(a) + '|>', file = sys.stderr)
except Exception as e:
    sys.stderr.write('ERROR: ' + str(e))
    sys.stdin.close()
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stderr.close()
    os.unlink(myStdin)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Output:

```
root:~# ./select.py &
[1] 4179
root:~# echo 'Hello World !!!' > ./inFIFO
root:~# [<_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <|Hello World !!!
|>

root:~# echo 'Hello World !!!' > ./inFIFO
[<_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
Message <|Hello World !!!
|>
root:~#
```